# Get index value from categorized List with itertools groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I have multiple list with tuple resulted from `nltk.Freqdist()` as follow :

```
totalist[0] = [('A',12),('C',1)] #index 0
totalist[1] = [('A',25),('X',3)] #index 1
totalist[2] = [('Z',3),('T',2)] #index 2
totalist[3] = [('Z',10),('M',8)] #index 3
totalist[4] = [('Z',8),('M',8)] #index 4
totalist[5] = [('C',10),('M',8)] #index 5
```

I want to get old index value even after this get grouped by `groupby`:

This is my code so far, but it wont work, it cant show index because of changing index from group by :

```
for key, group in groupby(totalist, lambda x: x[0][0]):
    for thing in group:
        #it should print it's old index value here 
    print(" ")
```

Is there any python way to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Assuming already sorted list

`groupby` assumes that the list is already sorted.
The example data satisfy this assumption.
You can use `enumerate` to preserve the original index and modify you key function accordingly:

```
for key, group in groupby(enumerate(totalist), lambda x: x[1][0][0]):
    print(key)
    for temp_thing in group:
        old_index, thing = temp_thing
        print('    ', old_index, thing)
```

Output:

```
A
     0 [('A', 12), ('C', 1)]
     1 [('A', 25), ('X', 3)]
Z
     2 [('Z', 3), ('T', 2)]
     3 [('Z', 10), ('M', 8)]
     4 [('Z', 8), ('M', 8)]
C
     5 [('C', 10), ('M', 8)]
```

### Assuming an unsorted list

This is a modified solution, if you need to sort your list first.
Best is to write one function that will be used for the sorting and the grouping:

```
def key_function(x):
    return x[1][0][0]
```

Now, use this function twice to get consistent sorting and grouping:

```
for key, group in groupby(sorted(enumerate(totalist), key=key_function), key_function):
    print(key)
    for temp_thing in group:
        old_index, thing = temp_thing
        print('    old index:', old_index)
        print('    thing:', thing)
```

Output:

```
A
    old index: 0
    thing: [('A', 12), ('C', 1)]
    old index: 1
    thing: [('A', 25), ('X', 3)]
C
    old index: 5
    thing: [('C', 10), ('M', 8)]
Z
    old index: 2
    thing: [('Z', 3), ('T', 2)]
    old index: 3
    thing: [('Z', 10), ('M', 8)]
    old index: 4
    thing: [('Z', 8), ('M', 8)]
```

Comment: If i sort the list will the index still the same or it gets change? since the index  actually represent document number if it sort I has to get old value

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Maybe you need my second approach, that sorts first.

Comment: Thank You!!!! it works... sorry I should have refresh my page before I ask that question to you... Thanks!!!

Comment: anyway what is  key_function(x): for?, and what's groupby(sorted(enumerate(totalist), key=key_function), key_function): use for?

Comment: Added some more explanation.